# 80 column rule for tex

Tags: formatting

In many other computing language, we still have reasons to stick into 80 column rule. e.g., easy to print out for checking, convenient for debugging etc.

I am not sure if you also use 80 column rule for `LaTeX` editing.  If so, please give some reasons why it is convinent.

PS: I am using `AUCtex` for editing.

Comment: A common editing style in LaTeX is to place one paragraph per line; another is one sentence per line.  Both of these can violate the 80-column rule, of course.  I tend to stick to the "72 column rule", being an old FORTRAN programmer.  The one-sentence per line is a good style for revision-control, when comparing (via diff) old manuscript versions to the current one.  The best style for you may also be driven by the features of your editor (e.g., auto-linebreak, justification, etc.).

Comment: I tend to put one "sentence unit" per line, i.e. a single line should make sense but not exceed 80 chars. This way you can read from the source comfortably and get a very clean history and diff from rev control. It could also help with error message but TeX is not very good in catching the error where it really happens...

Comment: I use the 'one-sentence-per-line' rule. The problem I have with the '80-columns' rule is that it is really hard to maintain. If I add a word to a line and the line is now more than 80 characters, I have to move a few words to the next line. But now the next line has more than 80 characters. It becomes too much of a hassle. I'm sure there are editors that take care of that for you, but then there's also the advantage of using `diff` tools (as others above have mentioned). Therefore, I stick to one sentence per line, with word wrap enabled on the 80th column in my editor.

Comment: AUCtex will easily help you follow such a rule with `auto-fill-mode`.  I use `70` columns.  My documents usually have a lot of mathematics, and short line lengths with indentation help to keep the structure clear.

Comment: One other reason for using shorter lines and hard wrap (I think that is the Emacs default), it that `synctex` becomes more precise. When performing backwards search you'll get closer to the actual area you want instead of having to scroll through a very long line of code. I still haven't figured out why editors link TeXmaker and TeXstudio haven't implemented hard warp.

Comment: Colored diffs make it possible to stick with fixed length lines and have readable differences.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Emacs, you can change the number of columns with C-x f. Which number is convinient for you, depends on your setup.

I'm using one main screen, which is put upright ("portrait"), and two others, which are "landscape" (if somebody could improve this sentence, I suspect it's pretty bad English). Emacs is fullscreen on this main screen. I prefer about 85 columns and a large font (the hardware on the chair isn't any longer capable of tiny letters).

But if your setup consists only of one screen and you have to share the screen e.g. with the pdf-viewer, I'd make lines shorter, because it's much easier to read the PDF and only type in the Emacs window. This requires inverse search...

Long story short: go on and try yourself.

Comment: oh, your english is okay, although i'd probably say "window" rather than "screen".  (i regard the screen as the whole viewing surface, and a window as a self-contained sub-unit.  and the larger the screen, the more windows it can accommodate.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you. I really meant "screen" = monitor, the piece of hardware; I built a small wall on my desk out of the three screens, but they are useful.